# Injection Dependy of a Multimodule Maven project in Maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, jar, maven-module

I have the following issue.
On one hand I have a multi module maven project, which I use maven install to write the .jar files in my local .m2 repository. This is working fine. Lets call it MultiA.

Now on the other hand, I have a spring boot project (lets call it SpringB) in which I bind the .jar files from my multi module maven project. This is working fine as well. When I execute my buisness logic from IntelliJ, I receive no issue, but when I build the project as a .jar, I receive an issue because the settings.properties file from MultiA are not found. I do not try to access settings.properties from SpringB, but I call a method from MultiA, which in return trys to access the settings properties.

I hope, this description helps and someone knows the answer to this problem.

Comment: It would be better to use a real repository manager instead of copying JARs around.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. While that is true and will be used in the future, I dont think it applys here. I dont copy .jars around. One project generates my .jar and writes them in the (local) repository. If there were to be written to a repository manager, they would still be multiple .jar files from MultiA. The binding in my SpringB project is like this:

Comment: `` `<dependency>
        <groupId>mulit.maven.project</groupId> \n
        <artifactId>ArtifactWithDependencyToAllOtherModules</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>` ``


So to my understanding a repository manager would just help in the way, that the "download" of the sources would ensue from my repository manager instead of my own local .m2 repository.